# Minimal ​API ASP.NET core: можно ли получить метод HTTP внутри FlatValidator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

У нас есть один микро-сервис с пробелами производительности. Мы думаем попробовать ускорить нём валидацию с помощью пакета [FlatValidator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlatValidator). Но у меня затруднения с получением метода HTTP внутри моего класса валидации. Можно ли это как-то сделать?

```
public record class RateRequest(Guid RateId, string Metadata);

public class RateRequestValidator : FlatValidator<RateRequest>
{
    public RateRequestValidator(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
        {
            ValidIf(m => m.RateId == Guid.Empty, m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", m => m.RateId);
        }
        else if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Put)
        {
            ValidIf(m => m.RateId != Guid.Empty, m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", m => m.RateId);
        }
    }
}
```

Это даёт непонятную ошибку: System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: System.Validation.IFlatValidator`1[RateRequest] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: RateRequestValidator'...

https://github.com/belset/FlatValidator

Answer (score 1):

Совет  @'Arthur Edgarov' оказался верным. Да, проблема не была связана с FlatValidator, к HttpContext нельзя обратиться напрямую, только через IHttpContextAccessor.

```
// needs to register HttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddFlatValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(RateRequestValidator).Assembly);

// ......

public record class RateRequest(Guid RateId, string Metadata);

public class RateRequestValidator : FlatValidator<RateRequest>
{
    // and pass IHttpContextAccessor as parameter instead of HttpContext
    public RateRequestValidator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
            {
                ValidIf(m => m.RateId == Guid.Empty, 
                        m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", 
                        m => m.RateId);
            }
            else if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Put)
            {
                ErrorIf(m => m.RateId == Guid.Empty,
                        m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", 
                        m => m.RateId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык